# Why is my method not printing objects from a subclass?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, subclass

this is my array:

```
public class TestProgram {

    public static final Room[] rooms = new Room[]
        {
            new Room ("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.0),
            new PremiumRoom ("POOL0001", "Poolside Terrace", 90.0, 1, 150, 50),
            new Room ("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35.0),
            new Room ("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35.0),
            new PremiumRoom ("POOL0002", "Poolside Private", 125.0, 2, 100, 75),
            new Room ("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52.0)
        };
}
```

and this is my method:

```
private static void displayrooms() {
    rooms[0].print();
    System.out.println();
    rooms[1].print();
    System.out.println();
    rooms[2].print();
    System.out.println();
    rooms[3].print();
    System.out.println();
    rooms[4].print();
    System.out.println();
    rooms[5].print();
}
```

However, when it prints out the list, it skips my PremiumRooms object. How do i solve this? The premiumroom is the subclass of Room.

this is what it output, the 2 premiumroom object is missing:

```
Room ID: GARDEN0001
Description: NorthWest Garden View
Daily-Rate: 45.0
Status: A


Room ID: GARDEN0003
Description: North Garden View
Daily-Rate: 35.0
Status: A

Room ID: GARDEN0005
Description: West Garden View
Daily-Rate: 35.0
Status: A


Room ID: GARDEN0004
Description: South Garden View
Daily-Rate: 52.0
Status: A
```

some of you asked for the `Room` and `PremiumRoom` codes. Here they are:

```
public Room(String roomId, String description, double dailyRate)
    {
        this.roomId = roomId;
        this.description = description;
        this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
        this.status = 'A';
    }

public PremiumRoom(String roomId, String description, double dailyRate, int freeNights, double discountRate, double nextBookingDiscountVoucher)
    {
        super(roomId, description, dailyRate);
        this.freeNights = freeNights;
        this.discountRate = discountRate;
        this.nextBookingDiscountVoucher = nextBookingDiscountVoucher;
    }
```

Comment: Share the `PremiumRoom` class source?

Comment: please show code of `print` method and also show code of `Room` and `PremiumRoom`  class

Comment: I bet on silently catching some Exception without printing the stacktrace :)

Comment: (How) is `PremiumRoom.print()` implemented? Also, you are doing at least 5x `println()`, thus you will have 5 line breaks, i.e. two empty lines. If not, we see the wrong code.

Comment: Where's the `toString`?

Comment: We didn't ask for the code of the *constructors*. We asked for the code of the class, in particular field definitions and the `print` methods are relevant, and anything else that this code refers to.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, i am really sorry, i am quite new to programming. What do you mean by particular field definitions? Should i just copy the whole class code here?

Comment: where is the print method(s) ?

Comment: @SadJavaBoi yes you have to provide whole class code.

Comment: I meant - the field definitions - what is `roomId`, `description` and all that, and the `print` method. Its best if you copy the whole class code, but remove code that is not relevant to the issue, such as getters and setters, other operations like booking a room etc. Keep the `print` method, the fields, and all methods that are called by the `print` method if there are any.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, omg while copying the files, i found the error. I realised the premiumroom class's print function wasnt written correctly. thanks guys for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your print method. If your Room class is like the one below then `displayrooms()` method will print for PremiumRooms as well.

```
public class Room {

    private String roomId;
    private String description;
    private double dailyRate;
    private char status;

    public Room(String roomId, String description, double dailyRate) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
        this.description = description;
        this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
        this.status = 'A';
    }

    public void print() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        str.append("Room ID: ").append(roomId).append("\n")
                .append("Description: ").append(description).append("\n")
                .append("Daily-Rate: ").append(dailyRate).append("\n")
                .append("Status: ").append(status);

        System.out.println(str.toString());
    }
}
```

However it'll omit any additional fields in Premium Room class. I order to include that too you need to override the print method in PremiumRoom Class like

```
public class PremiumRoom extends Room {

    private int freeNights;
    private double discountRate;
    private double nextBookingDiscountVoucher;

    public PremiumRoom(String roomId, String description, double dailyRate, int freeNights, double discountRate, double nextBookingDiscountVoucher) {
        super(roomId, description, dailyRate);
        this.freeNights = freeNights;
        this.discountRate = discountRate;
        this.nextBookingDiscountVoucher = nextBookingDiscountVoucher;
    }

    public void print() {
        super.print();
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        str.append("Free Nights: ").append(freeNights).append("\n")
                .append("Discount Rate: ").append(discountRate).append("\n")
                .append("Voucher: ").append(nextBookingDiscountVoucher);

        System.out.println(str.toString());
    }
}
```

And invoke like

```
public class TestProgram {

    public static final Room[] rooms = new Room[] {
            new Room("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.0),
            new PremiumRoom("POOL0001", "Poolside Terrace", 90.0, 1, 150, 50),
            new Room("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35.0),
            new Room("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35.0),
            new PremiumRoom("POOL0002", "Poolside Private", 125.0, 2, 100, 75),
            new Room("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52.0) 
    };

    private static void displayrooms() {
        rooms[0].print();
        System.out.println();
        rooms[1].print();
        System.out.println();
        rooms[2].print();
        System.out.println();
        rooms[3].print();
        System.out.println();
        rooms[4].print();
        System.out.println();
        rooms[5].print();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayrooms();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeap! that was the error that i figured. the premiumroom class did not have the method written properly. thanks for your help! :)